# When a goroutine blocks on I/O how does the scheduler identify that it has stopped blocking?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency

From what I've read [here](http://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler), the golang scheduler will automatically determine if a goroutine is blocking on I/O, and will automatically switch to processing others goroutines on a thread that isn't blocked.

What I'm wondering is how the scheduler then figures out that that goroutine has stopped blocking on I/O.

Does it just do some kind of polling every so often to check if it's still blocking? Is there some kind of background thread running that checks the status of all goroutines?

---

For example, if you were to do an HTTP GET request inside a goroutine that took 5s to get a response, it would block while waiting for the response, and the scheduler would switch to processing another goroutine. Now given that, when the server returns a response, how does the scheduler understand that the response has arrived, and it's time to go back to the goroutine that made the GET so that it can process the result of the GET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All I/O must be done through syscalls, and the way syscalls are implemented in Go, they are always called through code that is controlled by the runtime. This means that when you call a syscall, instead of just calling it directly (thus giving up control of the thread to the kernel), the runtime is notified of the syscall you want to make, and it does it on the goroutine's behalf. This allows it to, for example, do a non-blocking syscall instead of a blocking one (essentially telling the kernel, "please do this thing, but instead of blocking until it's done, return immediately, and let me know later once the result is ready"). This allows it to continue doing other work in the meantime.

Comment: I think I already understood this part of it. What I'm really curious about is how this part "let me know later once the result is read" is done. How does it check to see if "the result is read"

Comment: Usually using a signal. So some particular function that you specify will be called by the kernel when the IO is done and that function can handle it however it wants.

Comment: But how do you know that the IO is done? I understand the notion of a callback, but how can you figure out if the IO operation is completed like in the example I added above about a GET request.

Comment: Well first of all, from a syscall perspective, IO is more primitive than what you describe. A GET request, for example, consists of asking the kernel for bytes from a TCP stream until the whole request is read (these bytes will be requested in chunks, say 1024 bytes at a time). The scheduler won't have any conception of the high-level logic of "this is a GET request," but will instead just know "we asked for 1024 bytes, and now the kernel has said they're finally ready." The goroutine that initiated the request is then put back on the run queue so that it can be scheduled to run later.

Comment: (essentially, blocking or being "put to sleep" just means that a goroutine is removed from the pool of available goroutines that the scheduler can run next when it gets to make a scheduling decision. "Being woken back up" just means being put back into that pool)

Comment: The kernel actually performs the IO itself. Processes on their own can only access the CPU - anything beyond that is basically the processes saying, "dear kernel, please do the following on my behalf." This includes accessing any external devices (hard drive, keyboard, monitor, network card, etc), and even interacting with other processes.