# nodejs spawns threads implicitly by delegating the I/O to the kernel. How is this different than a server that makes a thread per request

Tags: node.js, multithreading, io, kernel

Following up on ideas from these two previous questions I had:

- [When a goroutine blocks on I/O how does the scheduler identify that it has stopped blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489498/when-a-goroutine-blocks-on-i-o-how-does-the-scheduler-identify-that-it-has-stopp)
- [When doing asynchronous I/O, how does the kernel determine if an I/O operation is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491094/when-doing-asynchronous-i-o-how-does-the-kernel-determine-if-an-i-o-operation-i)

I've been looking into nodejs recently. It's advertised as "single threaded", which is partially true since all your JS does run on one thread, but from what I've read, in the background, node achieves this by delegating the I/O tasks to the kernel so that it doesn't get stuck having to wait for the response.

What I'm having difficulty understanding is how this is any different than the paradigms where you explicitly are creating a thread per request.

Could someone explain the differences in depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be true if node created one thread for each I/O request. But, of course, it doesn't do that. It has an I/O engine that understands the best way to do I/O on each platform.

What nodejs hides from you is not some naive implementation where a scheduling entity waits for each request to complete, but a sophisticated implementation that understands the optimal way to do I/O on every platform on which it is implemented.

*Updates*:

> If both approaches need the kernel for I/O aren't they both creating a kernel thread per request?

No. There are lots of ways to use the kernel for I/O that don't require a kernel thread per request. They differ from platform to platform. Windows has IOCP. Linux has epoll. And so on.

> If nodejs somehow is using a fixed amount of threads and queueing the I/O operations, isn't that slower than a thread per request?

No, it's typically much faster for a variety of reasons that depend on the specifics of each platform. Here are a few advantages:

1. You can avoid "thundering herds" when lots of I/O completes at once. Instead, you can wake just the number of threads that can usefully run at the same time.
2. You can avoid needing lots of contexts switches to get all the different threads to execute. Instead, each thread can handle completion after completion.
3. You don't have to put each thread on a wait queue for each I/O operation. Instead, you can use a single wait queue for the group of threads.

Just to give you an idea of how significant it can be, consider the difference between using a thread per I/O and using epoll on Linux. If you use a thread per I/O, that means each I/O operation requires a thread to place itself on a wait queue, that thread to block, that thread to be unblocked, a context switch to occur to that thread, and that thread to remove itself from the wait queue.

By contrast, with epoll, a single thread can service any number of I/O completions without having to be rescheduled or added to or removed from a wait queue for each I/O. Similarly, a thread can issue a number of I/O requests without being descheduled. This difference is massive.

Comment: @AR7 Honestly, at the level of your questions, I think the most useful answer is just "node can do whatever works best on every platform, thread per I/O is not best on most platforms". That is, the benefit is that there's a layer of abstraction that avoids the programmer having to know how best to do I/O on every platform he wants his code to run on. Similar layers are things like libevent and boost ASIO.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I now need to read more about epoll and the other things you mentioned. I didn't know they existed.

Comment: And with one of these tools, you don't need to. That's their advantage. :)